# HTML markup is still stripped out, even if I am using the mimemail-message.tpl.php template

Tags: 6, ubercart, mimemail

I'm having an issue where confirmation emails from Ubercart seem to have  HTML markup removed. In my setup somehow the HTML markup in the Ubercart email template is being stripped when it reaches the mimemail template. A view of the source for emails sent shows that the HTML markup Mimemail puts into the message is there. It's just everything coming from Ubercart that is stripped out.

The line 35 of the mimemail-message.tpl.php template file is the following one

```php
<?php print $body ?>
```

This is where the problem lies. All the HTML markup above and below this makes it into the email. However, the HTML markup that should be in the `$body` variable is stripped out.

Is there something I could be missing in my settings?

Answer (score 0):

I added the htmlmail module and this fixed the problem.